ANTLR4: class ParseTree not defined
I'm using Eclipse/Java with ANTLR4 version 4.13.2. I have followed the example from the tutorial series from Jackie Wang (Youtube). I'm stuck in the main program. I get an error with the class 'ParseTree', which seems to be undefined.
Eclipse error message
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

//import org.antlr.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

import antlr.ExprLexer;
import antlr.ExprParser;
import antlr.ExprParser.ProgContext;
import expression.AntlrToProgram;
import expression.ExpressionProcessor;
import expression.Program;

public class ExpressionApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.err.print("Usage: file name");
        }
        else {
            String fileName = args[0];
            ExprParser parser = getParser(fileName);
            
            // Tell ANTLR to build a parse tree
            // parse from the start symbol 'prog'
            ParseTree xantlrAST = parser.prog();
            // Create a visitor for converting the parse tree into Program/Expression object
            AntlrToProgram progVisitor = new AntlrToProgram();
            Program prog = progVisitor.visit(antlrAST);
            
            if (progVisitor.semanticErrors.isEmpty()) {
                ExpressionProcessor ep = new ExpressionProcessor(prog.expressions);
                for (String evaluation: ep.getEvaluationResults()) {
                    System.out.println(evaluation);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (String err: progVisitor.semanticErrors) {
                    System.out.println(err);
                }
            }
                
        }
    }

The example from Jackie Wang has used the ANTLR4 version 4.8.
Even after searching the internet for a long time, I haven't been able to find any solution to my problem. I don't have much experience with Java and Eclipse and don't know how to help myself.
Thanks for any help
The defined grammar is very simple and the start symbol is 'prog':
//
grammar Expr;

/* The grammar name and file name must match */

@header {
    package antlr;
}

// 'prog' is the start variable
prog: (decl | expr)+ EOF            # Program
    ;

decl: ID ':' INT_TYPE '=' NUM       # Declaration
    ;

    /* ANTLR resolves ambiguities in favor of the alternative given first */
expr: expr '*' expr                 # Multiplication
    | expr '+' expr                 # Addition
    | ID                            # Variable
    | NUM                           # Number
    ;

/* Tokens */
ID : [a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*; // identifiers
NUM : '0' | '-'?[1-9][0-9]*;
INT_TYPE : 'INT';
COMMENT : '--' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
WS : [ \t\n]+ -> skip;

The use IDE is Eclipse and the screenshot shows the structure in the Project Explorer:
Structure in Eclipse Project Explorer
All visitor classes are defined and are located within the package 'expression'. The two warnings in the generated Java classes in package 'antlr' are caused by "@SuppressWarnings" showing in the following screenshot:
SuppressWarnings
The Build Path setup was made for Library and Source:
Build Path Library
Build Path Source
Are there any further information necessary which I shall provide?
If necessary, I can also make the project available if there is a possibility to do so here.

I would like to add one more piece of information:
If I change the faulty program line to choose the returned parameter type as 'ProgContext', this error message disappears. The change looks now like this:
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

//import org.antlr.runtime.tree.ParseTree;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CharStreams;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

import antlr.ExprLexer;
import antlr.ExprParser;
import antlr.ExprParser.ProgContext;
import expression.AntlrToProgram;
//import expression.Expression.*;
import expression.ExpressionProcessor;
import expression.Program;

public class ExpressionApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 1) {
            System.err.print("Usage: file name");
        }
        else {
            String fileName = args[0];
            ExprParser parser = getParser(fileName);
            
            // Tell ANTLR to build a parse tree
            // parse from the start symbol 'prog'
//          ParseTree xantlrAST = parser.prog();
            ProgContext antlrAST = parser.prog();
            // Create a visitor for converting the parse tree into Program/Expression object
            AntlrToProgram progVisitor = new AntlrToProgram();
            Program prog = progVisitor.visit(antlrAST);
            
            if (progVisitor.semanticErrors.isEmpty()) {
                ExpressionProcessor ep = new ExpressionProcessor(prog.expressions);
                for (String evaluation: ep.getEvaluationResults()) {
                    System.out.println(evaluation);
                }
            }
            else {
                for (String err: progVisitor.semanticErrors) {
                    System.out.println(err);
                }
            }
                
        }
    }

    /* 
     * Here the types of parser and lexer are specific to the
     * grammar name Expr.g4.
     */
    private static ExprParser getParser(String fileName) {
        ExprParser parser = null;
        
        try {
            CharStream input = CharStreams.fromFileName(fileName);
            ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(input);
            CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
            parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return parser;
    }
}

Now that the only error has disappeared, I can execute a RUN.
In this case I get the following message in the console:
Fehler: Hauptklasse app.ExpressionApp kann nicht initialisiert werden
Ursache: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree ParseTree
Translation:
Error: Main class app.ExpressionApp cannot be initialized
Cause: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTree
Console error message

You need to import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree, not org.antlr.runtime.tree.ParseTree (the latter is an ANTLR v3 class)

Thank you very much for your advice, it took me one step further. I changed the 'import' statement. The error disappeared and source code is now clean. - When I now run the code with configuration (console) I get exactly the same error messages as shown in my question (Console error message)

I tried also to use debug mode with a break point at the first instruction in the main class. The error message appears even before the program starts. - Unfortunately, I have no idea where I need to make a change now

If you're now having other problems, best close this question and create a new one: after all, your original question does not reflect the problem(s) you're now facing. And these small comment boxes are not suited to explain things properly.

Hi Bart, thanks for your help. I am very new on stackoverflow and have no idea how to close my question...

Closing is probably not possible. I meant "delete".
